# Fire javascript/jquery in jQuery dialog after .load

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery dialog which I fire from a list of items in a jTemplate:

```
<a href="#" class="view-map" id="{$T.Address.AddressCity.Lat}|{$T.Address.AddressCity.Lon}"><img src="/images/iconography/tiny-map.png" width="16" height="16" alt="See this address on a map..." title="See this address on a map..."></img></a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.view-map').live('click', function () {
            $('#map')
                .data('id', $(this).attr('id'))
                .dialog('open')

            ;
            return false;
        });

        $('#map').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizeable: false,
            position: 'top',
            modal: true,
            width: 650,
            open: function() {
                var location =  $(this).data('id').split('|');
                $(this).load('/components/google/map.aspx?lat=' + location[0] + '&lon=' + location[1]);
            },
            buttons: {
                'Ok': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
```

When the `map.aspx` page loads, I want the following javascript to fire (so I can get the map from Google):

```
function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 9,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(<%=Lat%>, <%=Lon%>),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('x-map-placeholder'), myOptions);
            document.getElementById('x-map-loader').style.display = 'none';
        }

        function loadScript() {
            alert("I'm away!");
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
        function toLower(s) {
            return s.toLowerCase();
        }
        function toFixed(n) {
            return n.toFixed(0);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;
```

Obviously it doesn't and I think this is because how the dialog is called - I understand that calling a dialog isn't `window.onload`ing and therefore won't fire the `loadScript`, but I'm not sure what to do to get it to fire....

Can anyone help? :)

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
$(function(){
function to fire 
});
```

Comment: Awesome! And super quick too. Thanks very much :) +1